# Error installing LilyPond with "chmod"

Tags: chmod, lilypond

I'm attempting to setup LilyPond so I can run it at the command line. I followed steps 1-3 here:

http://www.lilypond.org/macos-x.html

Step 4 ("Make the file executable: chmod u+x lilypond") returns an error. I get the error "chmod: lilypond: No such file or directory"

What gives?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Please see LilyPond email list archives for further info on this issue and its resolution. My main problem was with an Abjad file which can be easily modified. See answer, user Ralf, 9/25/15: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lilypond-user

Comment: You're not showing the steps before, in particular in which directory you were when you tried to make `lilypond` executable. It is probably in another directory.

Comment: Alternatively, you could install LilyPond using homebrew, though you'll first have to tap homebrew/tex: `brew tap homebrew/tex`, `brew install lilypond`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting homebrew. I've never used HB, and it didn't occur to me. I'm downloading it now and will update you on whether it fixes my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lyp](http://lyp.noteflakes.com/) to easily install and manage Lilypond. It takes care of downloading any version of Lilypond and makes it available on your commandline:

```
$ gem install lyp
$ lyp install lilypond
```